# Error method is not defined even though it seems correct

Tags: python

I would like to check an argument which user types on python.
I wrote a method to check if the argument is half-width character. You may not familiar if you are an English speaker, but some languages use the 2-word widths for 1 word. So I just wanted to write a method to check if a user is not using a unique language.
The method name is "has_digit(password)"

here is my entire code

```
from sys import argv 
import re

if 1 >= len(argv):
    print("Please type an argument")
    exit()
else:
    print("Checking password strength")

password = argv[1]

if has_digit(password) == True and has_lower_letter(password) == True and has_upper_letter(password) == True:
    print("This password is strong")
else:
    print("This passwor is weak. Please choose another password")

def has_digit(password):
    """
    パスワードに半角数字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        半角数字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[0-9]', password)
    return True if m else False


def has_lower_letter(password):
    """
    パスワードに英字小文字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        英字小文字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[a-z]', password)
    return True if m else False


def has_upper_letter(password):
    """
    パスワードに英字大文字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        英字大文字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[A-Z]', password)
    return True if m else False
```

error message

```
  File "pw_check.py", line 12, in <module>
    if has_digit(password) == True and has_lower_letter(password) == True and has_upper_letter(password) == True:
NameError: name 'has_digit' is not defined
```

How can I fix this error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to call the function *after* it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It's just how python parses your file. Your function should be defined before you call it, like :

```py
from sys import argv 
import re
def has_digit(password):
    """
    パスワードに半角数字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        半角数字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[0-9]', password)
    return True if m else False


def has_lower_letter(password):
    """
    パスワードに英字小文字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        英字小文字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[a-z]', password)
    return True if m else False


def has_upper_letter(password):
    """
    パスワードに英字大文字が含まれるかをチェックします。
    Args:
        チェック対象のパスワード
    Returns:
        英字大文字を含んでいればTrue
    """
    m = re.search(r'[A-Z]', password)
    return True if m else False
if 1 >= len(argv):
    print("Please type an argument")
    exit()
else:
    print("Checking password strength")

password = argv[1]

if has_digit(password) == True and has_lower_letter(password) == True and has_upper_letter(password) == True:
    print("This password is strong")
else:
    print("This passwor is weak. Please choose another password")
```